# What is the 'new' login.defs file in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users

I am currently going through TestOut for my Linux+ certification, and I got to the section on users and groups. The instructor demonstrated that the login.defs file has been used to change default user information. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 to follow along, and when I cat the file I get this message:

[image: Screenshot of cat output]

It says that its now obsolete. Where can I manipulate these values in the current version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the warning message. There is no "new login.defs"; the existing file is still used, but no longer supports the 4 options following the warning.

---

Some of those options haven't just moved elsewhere; they have been removed entirely. For example, `CLOSE_SESSIONS` is enabled permanently, as disabling it creates issues with quite a few PAM modules.

The other options have never been supported by the corresponding PAM modules; they only work on systems with PAM-less login. The corresponding PAM option would be specified in `/etc/pam.d` instead.

- Most authentication modules, e.g. pam_unix(8), do not allow customizing the password prompt in any way.
- The pam_mail(8) module accepts `dir=` for a Maildir-format (aka qmail) location.
- `NO_PASSWORD_CONSOLE` *could* be emulated via the pam_succeed_if(8) module.

---

Relevant changelogs:

- https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/ChangeLog#L11569
- https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/ChangeLog#L11623
- https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/ChangeLog#L12901
- https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/ChangeLog#L13872